# $\left|\int_0^1 \left(\text{sign $m(t)$}\right) \cdot\,f(t)dt\right|<\infty$ but $\int_0^1f(t)dt=\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m(t)$, $f(t)$ are functions on $[0;1]$ which are assumed to be measurable, $m(t)\neq0$ almost everywhere and $f(t)\geq0$ for all $t$ belongs to the interval $[0;1]$. Let me recall that $\text{sgn}m(t)=\begin{cases}0 \quad\text{if $m(t)=0$}&\\ 1\quad\text{if $m(t)>0$ and}&\\ -1\quad\text{if $m(t)<0$.}\end{cases}$.

It seems that there exist such functions $m$ and $f$ so that  $\left|\int\limits_0^1 \left(\text{sign $m(t)$}\right)\cdot\,f(t)dt\right|<\infty$ but $\int\limits_0^1f(t)dt=\infty$, but I get stuck to construct such functions. So do  there exist such functions?

Comment: Perhaps this might give you some inspiration. $\sum 1/n \to \infty$, but $\sum (-1)^n /n$ converges.

Comment: Here's a simple example; we can take $m(t)=0$, in which case $\int_0^1(sign m(t))f(t)=0$ for any $f(t)$.  Now just pick $f(t)$ whose integral diverges.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot that $m(t)$ should be nonzero for almost everywhere

Answer (score 5):

Let $m(t)$ be $\sin(t)$ , and $f(t)= 1/t$.
Now $\int\limits_0^1f(t)dt=\infty$ , and $\left|\int\limits_0^1\sin(t)f(t)dt \right|< \infty$.
if you do not need $m(t)$ to be continuous , you can take $m(t) = (-1)^n$ for each $n \in {N}$.

Comment: I agree that your example is true in some sense. Here I assume that $f$ is determine on $[0;1]$, it means $f(0)$ is a real number. Unlickily, your example $f(0)=\infty$.

Comment: ok than you can take $f(x)=1/(x-1/2)$
and if f(x) is a real number for any x in [0,1] than the integral of f wil be smaller than infinity

Comment: You mean $f(x)=\frac1{x-1/2}$ if $x\neq 1/2$ and $c$ if $x=1/2$, where $c\in\mathbb R$ ? What is $m(x)$?

Comment: $m(x)$ will be $sin(x)$